# I want to extract a string after the specific character is the character exists in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column which have data like

| ss | ss_period (varchar) |
| --- | --- |
| s1 | 01/01/2020-31/01/2020 |
| s2 | 01/08/2019-31/08/2019 |
| s3 | ABC 1/4/2020-30/4/2020 |
| s4 | DEF GHI 1/4/2020-30/4/2020 |
| s5 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP |

how can i get the result like this

| ss | ss_period | ss_period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | 01/01/2020 | 31/01/2020 |
| s2 | 01/08/2019 | 31/08/2019 |
| s3 | 1/4/2020 | 30/4/2020 |
| s4 | 1/4/2020 | 30/4/2020 |
| s5 | null | null |

I try to use strpos and split_part but it doesn't work for me now.
I think i should remove text except "-" and "/" first.
but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you please show your best not working attempt? Then we could improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using regex matching and replacements to do the heavy lifting.  First check that an `ss_period` input value have two dates in the hyphen-separated format you expect.  If so, then use regex replacements with capture groups to isolate each date.  If not, then just assign a default value of `NULL`.

```sql
SELECT
    ss,
    CASE WHEN ss_period ~ '.*\d+/\d+/\d+-\d+/\d+/\d+.*'
         THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(ss_period, '^.*(\d+/\d+/\d+)-.*$', '\1')
    END AS ss_period_start,
    CASE WHEN ss_period ~ '.*\d+/\d+/\d+-\d+/\d+/\d+.*'
         THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(ss_period, '^.*-(\d+/\d+/\d+).*$', '\1')
    END AS ss_period_end
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ss;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `STRPOS()` and `SPLIT_PART()` functions by means of applying `CROSS` and `LEFT JOIN`s recursively such as

```
SELECT t.ss, 
       SPLIT_PART(str, '-', 1) AS ss_period1, SPLIT_PART(str, '-', 2) AS ss_period2
  FROM t
  LEFT JOIN
  (
   SELECT ss, SPLIT_PART(ss_period, ' ', n) AS str
     FROM t
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(ss_period, '[^ ]', '', 'g'))+1) AS n
    WHERE STRPOS(SPLIT_PART(ss_period, ' ', n),'-') > 0 
   ) AS tt
    ON tt.ss = t.ss
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=966371db259f66ccbe7f76ff5c045474)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I view this as a two-part problem.  First, find the string that has the range.  Then split it into two pieces.

For the first part, `regexp_match()` seems to do the trick.  For the second, `split_part()`:

```
select t.*, split_part(v.rng, '-', 1), split_part(v.rng, '-', 2)
from t cross join lateral
     (values ((regexp_match(ss_period, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}'))[1])
     ) v(rng);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72e2b5b4994582f8cfa1fcffec250672) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To go in the same direction of Tim's answer, you can use the `regexp_match()` function :

> ```
> SELECT ss
>      , (regexp_match(ss_period, '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'))[1] AS ss_period_start
>      , right((regexp_match(ss_period, '-\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}'))[1], -1) AS ss_period_end
>   FROM your_table ;
> ```